# Query multiple dataframes and plot group histogram

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

In have six dataframes , that contain temperatures in years 2016 , 2017 and 2018. 
Dataset names are :

East2016,West2016

East2017,West2017

East2018,West2018

Each of them has a column with the name : Temperature.

I need to query where Temperature>30 ,then compare them in a group histogram like .

I need to know  how much percentage in 2016 East and West temperature goes to more than 30. The same for 2017 and 2018.

Put them all in one histogram, such that X-axis represents the year and Y-axis for percentage .

For example:   plot East2016 and West2016 with histograms beside each other one in red (east) and the other in blue (west) both have one X label ( 2016) .   As in the photo.[image: Example photo]

Then repeat this for the other two pairs (East2017,West2017) and (East2018,West2018) .

I am working with Plotly and Pandas .

Comment: Unfortunately your sentences are hard to follow. Could you please reformulate your question and also add code.

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 I will. Thank you

Comment: Do not forget to mention the packages you work with. Especially for making the histograms.

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353 please see if the question is clear now.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't see what you mean by Dataset. I strongly advise that you post your actual code and/or some thinned down code example. In other words, how does your objects work?

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353I will attach a drawn photo

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353   I hope the photo is clear .